# Keep w3wp process alive or automatically attached while debugging WCF service hosted in IIS

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio, debugging, iis

I'm debugging a WCF Service that hosted in IIS 6 with VS 2008.  To do so, I just attach to the w3wp.exe process, and I'm good to go.

However, it's quite annoying that this process seems to be killed all the time, like every time I stop debugging, or if I stop actively using the service for a few minutes.  That means almost every time I invoke a service method and want to debug, I have to keep repeatedly attaching to the process.

Is there any way to easily keep the process alive, or maybe get the debugger to automatically attach to it when it gets started?

I'm thinking there's probably some IIS config that might help here, but I can't find it.

I know I can write a console app to host in just for debugging, but I'd rather not have to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable:

- the application pool's recycling feature
- the pool's idle timeout

In both cases you can find this in IIS Manager under:

```
Application Pools -> Properties for your pool -> Recycling tab or Performance tab
```

That should keep the worker process alive.

Comment: Thanks.  I've set both of those.  I still seem to lose my attachment to the process in Visual Studio alot though; I guess every time you stop debugging, you have to reattach, right?  Can you set a process for it to automatically reattach to, so I don't have to pick it from a list every time?

Comment: I was never able to find a way to do that in VS2008 or VS2010. I even tried writing a macro but it would sometimes lock up VS. I feel your pain in this respect.